# What to do if I can't find the person whom I'm indebted some money to?

Tags: money

I am indebted some money to a person whom I can't find. This debt is a headache to me.
I've looked for this person for some years now, but still no trace!!!

What should I do in this situation? I'm afraid if I would die before clearing the debts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "If you know that you owe somebody and how much you owe him, but you
>   cannot find him, or you know the amount you owe but you do not know to
>   whom it is owed, then give that amount in charity on that person's
>   behalf.
>
> If he comes along later, give him the choice between approving of the
>   charity and gaining the reward for it, or asking you to pay him back,
>   in which case the reward (for giving charity) will be yours"

Sheikh Muhammed Salih Al-Munajjid (Islam Q&A #5979)